# Are the discrete and trivial topologies dual in some category theory sense?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

[Wikipedia's page about the trivial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology) says it is also commonly called the *codiscrete* topology. In it, it also says

> In some sense the opposite of the trivial topology is the discrete topology, in which every subset is open.

This leads to the question: does the *codiscrete* result from reversing arrows on some category from the discrete topology?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken they are the terminal and initial topologies in the fiber of the forgetful functor to sets. So in this sense they are dual I guess. Also there should be a more precise way to say. What follow is higly unsure, take it as a hint. If you compose the forgetful functor alternatively with the discrete and codiscrete functor,the fact they are adjoin, implies that you obtsin two different idenpotent endofunctors on Top, one which incarnates discretness and the other codiscretness. And those two should be related (adjoint?).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\Gamma:\mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Set}$ be the forgetful functor. Then, $\Gamma$ has a left adjoint $\text{Disc}$, which equips a set with the discrete topology, and a right adjoint $\text{Codisc}$, which equips a set with the trivial (or *codiscrete category*).

See [nlab's page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/discrete+and+indiscrete+topology) for more details.